# How can I force a VirtualBox VM to reload after a crash?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Virtual Box for a production server, but sometimes.. it crash! 
How to force virtualbox to reload it ? 
Thanks!

Comment: No

Just, no. Using VirtualBox to maintain a production server is a very bad idea. VirtualBox is for doing tests, nothing mission critical.

Comment: This is like using a crisp packet for a condom.. Use the right tools for the job.

Comment: Painful, cheap, likely to break at the worst possible moment.  Quite an apt analogy.

Comment: ...and last seen used in production behind the bike sheds by a girl who now works at McD's...

Comment: pics or it didnt happen.

Comment: Why so many "undervote" ... virtualbox is a virtualization solution that can ...just work, imho.

Comment: So many downvotes, because we know better than you!

Comment: Err… except IT'S NOT "JUST WORKING".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dump VIrtualBox and use a proper virtualization technology.

To start with:

> it crash!

Ok, now I am not used to VirutalBox - I use Hyper-V and have experience with VmWare, and outside a power or hardware failures I never had any of my servers just crash.

1. You likely have borked drivers.
2. Proper **server** virtualization products support autostart. Xen, XVM, Hyper-V, VmWare. All have a free version even. VirtualBox is not a server system. It was not planned as one, not programmed to be one.

Dump VirtualBox, install some proper Hypervisor, be happy.